# PHP undefined class for config file

Tags: php

I have Database.php and Config.php in the same location.  In Database.php, if I do the following it works

```
<?php
class Database
{
    const DB_ADAPTER = 'mysql';
    const DB_USER = 'something';
    const DB_PASSWORD = 'something';
    const DB_DATABASE = 'something';
    const DB_HOST = "localhost";
    const DB_CHARSET = "utf8";

    /* All my code */

     $dns = self::DB_ADAPTER . ':host=' . self::DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . self::DB_DATABASE;
            self::$dbLink = new \PDO($dns, self::DB_USER, self::DB_PASSWORD);

}
```

If I move the constants to Config.php and change the above to the following

```
<?php

include('Config.php');

class Database
{
    /** @var PDO The shared database link. */
    protected static $dbLink;

    /* All my code */

     $dns = Config::DB_ADAPTER . ':host=' . Config::DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . Config::DB_DATABASE;
            self::$dbLink = new \PDO($dns, Config::DB_USER, Config::DB_PASSWORD);

}
```

It fails with a Undefined class constant 'DB_ADAPTER' in Database.php (if i remove DB_ADAPTER, it will fail on the next constant).

Why would this be happening?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

```
<?php

/**
 * Class containing configuration details
 */
class Config
{
    const DB_ADAPTER = 'mysql';
    const DB_USER = 'something';
    const DB_PASSWORD = 'something';
    const DB_DATABASE = 'something_portal_db';
    const DB_HOST = "localhost";
    const DB_CHARSET = "utf8";
}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior: https://eval.in/408233

Comment: When you moved it to Config.php did you also change the name of the class to Config?

Comment: I have updated the OP to show Config.php.  Initially, it was config.php, but I changed it to be Config.php.

Comment: your line of code for `$dns` needs to be in a function.

Comment: It is, I am just showing a snippet of whats in the function where the error occurs

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you make them <strike>static and</strike> public to use without object creation?

```
<?php

/**
 * Class containing configuration details
 */
class Config
{
    public const DB_ADAPTER = 'mysql';
    public const DB_USER = 'something';
    public const DB_PASSWORD = 'something';
    public const DB_DATABASE = 'something_portal_db';
    public const DB_HOST = "localhost";
    public const DB_CHARSET = "utf8";
}
```

Comment: PHPStorm seems to show a lot of red errors if I make them static

Comment: what if you simply make them public? @NickPrice